# Sql Server, number of rows with stored procedures

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a project, its written in php and running on sql server.
They are using stored procedures. I noticed that when they want to get number of rows from a procedure, they used very slow method. 
Its going while() function and counting every row, then returning total number of count.
Ex:

```
function numrow($procedure, $inputs) {
$callpro= callPro($procedure, $inputs);
while ($row = getrow($callpro)) {
$number++;
}
$numrows = $number;
return $numrows;
}
```

is there any way to speed this method ? i tried to use sqlsrv_num_rows, but its gives nothing on procedures.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `mssql_num_rows()` which return the number of rows in a result set. So something like:

$numrows = mssql_num_rows($reslutSet)

should help. 
Note: The $resultSet has to be a result of the call `mssql_query()`. So my solution is dependand on how `callPro()` is implemented.